# How to put a unique material on duplicated objects separately?

Tags: materials, objects

I've a sphere and then duplicate it. In object tree they are displayed as three siblings. I selected one of them and created a green glass material through node editor however this material was assigned to all three spheres. I confirmed that my selection is only on one sphere. What am I missing?

Comment: this also might help understanding how materials are linked to either mesh or object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282475/assign-different-materials-to-different-object-copies

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, when you duplicate an object in Blender, the copy is a new object but will still share some data with the original (by default this includes materials and textures) and will copy other data, like the mesh (which allows you edit each independently). Because of this, all these objects will share the material the original object has.

To get each object to have its own unique material, you can select them all, go the *3d view* header and use *Object > Make Single User > Object & Data & Materials + Tex*. Or, you can select each sphere, go the material panel and click the *number* [image] beside it to make it unique to *that* sphere.

Comment: In 2.81a it has changed to Object > Make Links > Materials

Answer (score 1):

As of Blender 3.6.1, to create unique materials for multiple duplicated objects, select the objects and in the 3D View header menu go to:

*Object > Relations > Make Single User > Materials*