# modifiers on duplicated meshes applying to unselected part of duplicated+original mesh?

Tags: mesh, materials

I'm a beginner.

When I attempt to put a material on a duplicated mesh, the material only applies to the deselected mesh, including the original mesh that was duplicated, and changes freely as my selection changes.

I cannot for the life of me unlink the duplicated object from the original object. When I try to go into object mode it selects the original + the duplicated mesh, and attempting to deselect one deselects both of them, so I can't use Object > Make Single User.

Comment: Looks like your objects are joined into one, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object. Note though that even after separating objects will share the same material, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/how-to-put-a-unique-material-on-duplicated-objects-separately