# Why is it making the same material for two different objects?

Tags: materials

When I was working on something, I wanted one of the objects to be solid and the other to be material. But when I finished making the first thing solid when I tried making the other thing material but it turned the first thing into material too. I searched up and tried some answers, but it didn't work, please help me.

Comment: You just have the same material on both objects.  Simply create another material and assign it to only one of the objects.  All mesh objects with faces have a material, even if it's just the default Diffuse.  It's what defines how the light paths should be handled.

Comment: can you show the picture of the steps, sorry i'm a beginner to blender..

Comment: Do both objects share the same mesh?

Comment: i'm not sure, i probably do.

Comment: If you duplicated these objects after assigning a material to them then they still share the same one, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/how-to-put-a-unique-material-on-duplicated-objects-separately. Your question can have different solutions depending on your exact case, [edit] it and provide more information with screenshots.

Comment: It depends on the render engine, what Blender version, and whether or not you're in Object Mode or Edit Mode.  Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Select the first object, and in the material panel, click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button (surrounded by a pink frame in the picture) to create a first material (named *Material.001*) and change its diffuse color.

[image]

Select the second object, and in the material panel, press again the <kbd>+</kbd> button to create a second material (named *Material.002*) and change its diffuse color.

Each object should have a different color.

[image]