# Why do all the objects get the same color?

Tags: objects, color, parent, color-management, groups

I try to give different base colours to my objects but when I define a base colour for one object, a couple of objects get the same colour at the same time. made a new material for those ones to separate their material from each other but when I add the base colour to those it's not showing it. then I went to every object and pressed  P to separate them from each other but it didn't help. I also unwrapped the object just to see if it helps. but it didn't.

Can you help me figure out what is the problem?

Thank you!

[image: coloring all together :(]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/how-to-put-a-unique-material-on-duplicated-objects-separately

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you haven't *assigned* the material to that object/mesh.

Just select that object and go into *Edit Mode*. Then select the whole of that part by pressing `L` to select linked or `A` to select all.

Then just press the assign button here:

[image]