# assigning multiple meshes the same material

Tags: materials

Is there a way to select multiple objects and assign a material to all of them at once. Any attempt I have made only applies it to the last object selected.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Although not necessarily what was intended in this question, adding a material to an object and to a mesh are two different things.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I am trying to add it to multiple objects not meshes.

Comment: With object with material already assigned press Ctrl+L > materials. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/copy-material-to-another-object